# What are the Hardware Rx/Tx Queue in Ethernet controller

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I have very basic question regarding Rx/Tx Hardware Queues in Ethernet Controller, what its used for ?

While looking at the following driver in Linux kernel, its seems like it is used to carry DMA descriptors ?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/genet/bcmgenet.c#L2276

Comment: The typical Ethernet MAC chip has queues for Ethernet frames.

Comment: @sawdust, Thanks for reply. Actually I don't see how these queues are H/W specific, they are simply implemented as arrays(unlike descriptor that has base address onto the device, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/genet/bcmgenet.c#L2566).

Comment: You need to study the manufacturer's datasheet for the EMAC, which should have the description of how those queues work.  Unless you are already familiar with such devices, then just reading the source code will not explain anything.  Even the datasheet might assume a high-level of knowledge and/or experience with Ethernet reception/transmission.

Comment: @sawdust, actually datasheet for this EMAC is not available publicly, so all I can do is to read the source code :(

Answer (score 10):

You are correct, the rx/tx queues contain DMA descriptors for incoming and outgoing packets.

If you are curious how network drivers work, I recommend looking at the ixy userspace network driver: https://github.com/emmericp/ixy

The code is relatively simple and very well commented, and there is a paper which explains how it works: https://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/bibtex/publications/papers/ixy-writing-user-space-network-drivers.pdf

See section 4.1 *NIC Ring API* in the paper for an explanation of the receive (rx) and transmit (tx) queues:

> NICs expose multiple circular buffers called queues or rings to transfer packets. The simplest setup uses only one receive and one transmit queue. Multiple transmit queues are merged on the NIC, incoming traffic is split according to filters or a hashing algorithm if multiple receive queues are configured. Both receive and transmit rings work in a similar way: the driver programs a physical base address and the size of the ring. It then fills the memory area with *DMA descriptors*, i.e., pointers to physical addresses where the packet data is stored with some metadata. Sending and receiving packets is done by passing ownership of the DMA descriptors between driver and hardware via a head and a tail pointer. The driver controls the tail, the hardware the head. Both pointers are stored in device registers accessible via MMIO.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your reply, there is this line mentioned in noted you shared "the driver programs a physical base address and the size of the ring" but I couldn't find it in driver I am looking into, all I can see is https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/genet/bcmgenet.h#L618, ring is simply an array with index into it that describes the various queues. With each queue has number of descriptors.

Comment: That's a good question. I took a quick look at that driver and could not find it.